# Graphs of electric quantities for cell with internal resistance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits

A cell of EMF $E$ and internal resistance $r$ is connected to an external resistance $R$. Draw graphs to show the variation of 
(a) $E$ with $R$, and
(b) terminal potential difference $V$ of the cell with the current $I$ drawn from the cell.

I'm not sure about (a), but, for (b), I don't know which formula to use: $V = IR$ or $V = E - Ir$, since they give different graphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, for example the page at http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/302l/lectures/node57.html . It seems that the EMF E is a characteristic of the cell. So it should be constant, whatever hapens that is non-destructive.

Regarding the second question, both formulae are correct, and both refer to the same voltage V between the points A and B in the figure of the page referenced above. So, if they give different graphs, you are surely misunderstanding something.
Or is it only a matter of sign, of positive or negative value?

It is important to understand the difference between the emf E and the voltage V between the terminals of the cell,  due to a voltage loss in the internal resistor of the cell.